# Spring Security - How to know if Sid is a principal or authority

Tags: spring-security

I would like to know whether the retrieved sid ("currentSid") from a permission in the acl_entry table is that of a principal or authority.

```java
for (int j = 0; j < acl.getEntries().size(); j++) {
    String currentPermissionPattern = acl.getEntries().get(j).getPermission().getPattern();
    String currentSid = acl.getEntries().get(j).getSid().toString();       
}
```

I am currently storing currentSid as string. Lets say I stored it as Sid, how can I know if this Sid belongs to a user or a role.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
if (acl.getEntries().get(j).getSid() instanceof GrantedAuthoritySid) {
    GrantedAuthoritySid sid = (GrantedAuthoritySid) acl.getEntries().get(j).getSid();
    // it's role
} else {
    PrincipalSid sid = (PrincipalSid) acl.getEntries().get(j).getSid();
    // it's user
}
```